# WebServer ESP8266

Tags: сервер, arduino, esp8266

Нужна помощь с созданием html странички на ESP8266. В интернете я не нашел как это сделать без подключения к WiFi роутеру. Мне нужно что бы эта страничка поддерживалась самой esp8266, и к ней был доступ по IP. Я думаю что это возможно, так как я видел что Deauther на базе этой платы, создаёт такую страницу без подключения к WiFi. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать, или где найти об этом информацию?

Comment: Подключение по WiFi(либо Ethernet если сможете подключить, но нет особого смысла для ESP) + проброс 80-го порта на роутере. Других вариантов не вижу.

Comment: Создать точку доступа , и отдавать html при подключении.

Comment: https://circuits4you.com/2016/12/16/esp8266-web-server-ap/

Answer (score 0):

[Эта](https://circuits4you.com/2016/12/16/esp8266-web-server-ap/) статья советует : "при подключении у точке доступа , силами ESP8266  отдавать HTML страничку" .
Пример кода:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
 
//SSID and Password to your ESP Access Point
const char* ssid = "ESPWebServer";
const char* password = "12345678";
 
ESP8266WebServer server(80); //Server on port 80
 
//==============================================================
//     This rutine is exicuted when you open its IP in browser
//==============================================================
void handleRoot() {
  server.send(200, "text/plain", "hello from esp8266!");
}
 
//===============================================================
//                  SETUP
//===============================================================
void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);           //Only Access point
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);  //Start HOTspot removing password will disable security
 
  IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP(); //Get IP address
  Serial.print("HotSpt IP:");
  Serial.println(myIP);
 
  server.on("/", handleRoot);      //Which routine to handle at root location
 
  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
//===============================================================
//                     LOOP
//===============================================================
void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();          //Handle client requests
}
```